# Reproducing paper results about a wavelet transformation using python

Tags: matlab, python, wavelet, time-series, r

I have been reading this PhD theis about wavelets and I am trying to reproduce some of the results but I don't know the specific code to use to generate similar results.

The original time series looks like this:
[image]

Then, the paper says:

> The customer demand is transformed to the wavelet domain by the
>   non-decimated wavelet transform performed with the Symmlet 8 filter.
>   Figure 47 shows customer demand in the wavelet domain.

[image]

Can someone point me out how to reproduce this results using Python (then R, then matlab, in that order of preference)

NOTE: link to document, page 122: [A Multiscale Forecasting Methodology for Power Plant Fleet Management A Thesis](https://smartech.gatech.edu/bitstream/handle/1853/6849/chen_hongmei_200505_phd.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), Hongmei Chen, Feb. 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a fake imitation of your data, here is a first try in Matlab, which I may improve later on. It uses the stationary wavelet transform `swt.m`:

```
nSample = 256;
timeOnset = 25;

time = linspace(1,nSample,nSample)';
%ramp = max(time,timeOnset)/nSample;
ramp = abs(time-timeOnset)/nSample;

nLevel1 = 4;
nLevel2 = 5;
waveletName = 'sym8';
data = 0.15*((1+rand(nSample,1)/1).^0.5).*sin(2*pi*time/nSample*42)+0.65*(ramp+1);
dataSWT1 = swt(data,nLevel1,waveletName);
dataSWT2 = swt(data,nLevel2,waveletName);
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(time,data);axis tight
subplot(3,1,2);
imagesc(dataSWT1);axis tight
xlabel([num2str(nLevel1),' levels'])
subplot(3,1,3);
imagesc(dataSWT2);axis tight
xlabel([num2str(nLevel2),' levels'])
```

[image: data and stationary wavelet transform]

Comment: thanks this is great!  Short follow-up Q, the 4-level and 5-level wavelet plots plot the detail coefficients, am I right?  How did you select those since I see in your code dataSWT1 = swt(data,nLevel1,waveletName); which in my mind contains both, the approximation and the detail coefficients.

Comment: I was mistaken by the paper notations. To me, 1-level splits data into 2 subbands: one for the approximation, one for the details. 2-level splits the former approximation into 2 subbands: one for the second-level approximation, one for the second-level details. So to reproduce the paper, you should use 3-level and 4-level in my code. The blueish bands are details. The green-yellow is approximation. To select details only, skip the last row: `dataSWT1(1:end-1,:)`.